ASP.NET is triggering events sequentially instead of as they happen. How do I get it to just trigger all the events as they happen?
I have a bunch of asp:ListBox, and I want to only handle the most recent event from any one of them. However, C# seems to only execute a single thread at a time, no matter how many times I click.  For example, I click once in each of my four listboxes, and my debug messages will show that only one event is being processed at a time.
"12:00:00 Listbox1_Method starting"
"12:00:02 Listbox1_Method ending"
"12:00:02 Listbox2_Method starting"
"12:00:04 Listbox2_Method ending"
"12:00:04 Listbox3_Method starting"
"12:00:06 Listbox3_Method ending
"12:00:06 Listbox4_Method starting"
"12:00:08 Listbox4_Method ending"

In extreme cases, I have to wait minutes before it even begins to process the final click. Since it's waiting for one thread to complete before triggering the next, that means I can't use regular multithreading solutions like locks or queues. I can only assume that there's some higher-level server setting that's stopping my page from executing multiple threads at once. What can I do to get it to run more threads?
My code looks like this:
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
   <asp:ListBox ID="Listbox1" runat="server" Width="200px" Height="150px" TabIndex="1" CssClass="pList1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Listbox1_Method" AutoPostBack="true" SelectionMode="Single"></asp:ListBox>
   <asp:ListBox ID="Listbox2" runat="server" Width="200px" Height="150px" TabIndex="1" CssClass="pList1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Listbox2_Method" AutoPostBack="true" SelectionMode="Single"></asp:ListBox>
   <asp:ListBox ID="Listbox3" runat="server" Width="200px" Height="150px" TabIndex="1" CssClass="pList1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Listbox3_Method" AutoPostBack="true" SelectionMode="Single"></asp:ListBox>
   <asp:ListBox ID="Listbox4" runat="server" Width="200px" Height="150px" TabIndex="1" CssClass="pList1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Listbox4_Method" AutoPostBack="true" SelectionMode="Single"></asp:ListBox>
</ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Listbox1"  EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Listbox2"  EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Listbox3"  EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Listbox4"  EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
  </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>


I suggest you open your browser developer tools, particularly the network tab, to understand what is going on here. Then you might want to rethink your design to use client side scripting.

Can you share the code that is printing statements?

It's loading data from a server, and using it to update the listbox contents.

Threads may not speed things up. It looks like you're doing server calls so it's going to be sequential. You would need to make the click trigger an action and return immediately, then poll for completion of those tasks if you want the page to appear performant.
